# TabWidget doesn't look right in Android 2.1 devices

Tags: android, android-layout

My application has `android:targetSdkVersion` set to 11. It uses `TabHost` and `TabWidget` with two tabs. However, the `android:minSdkVersion` is set to 7 (Android 2.1).

I use the Android Support Library (`android-support-v13.jar`). My tabs look fine everywhere I've been able to test, except in 2.1 where they appear to be clipping parts of the view that forms the tab's content. This problem in reproducible in the emulator as well.

Here's the relevant section of the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/repeat_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android: />

        <FrameLayout>
        ...
        </FrameLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's how I expect the tabs to look:

[image: Expected]

Here's what I get in 2.3 devices:

[image: Unexpected]

Basically, it seems the Tabs are taller than they need to be and also unnecessarily overlapping with the contents of the `FrameLayout` below.

**SOLUTION:**
Mostly for future visitors, if you're looking to have you tabs appear consistent on all platforms down to 2.1, the only solution is to use custom Tab views. You'll find an excellent [tutorial](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136) here.

Comment: Android 2.3 or 2.1?? API 7 is 2.1

Comment: Sorry, it's 2.1 API 7. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: for `TabHost` try `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` does take care of the tab width. They now expand to occupy the whole screen width. But the overlap with the `FrameLayout` below still occurs.

Comment: see the answer posted by @RKN. It will solve your problem..I guess

Comment: I suggest you to set tabs width programmactically depending on the screen size / 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Hope it helps...!! Cheers...

Comment: Works like a charm but is there any way to make the `TabWidget` appear with my custom background as they do in the first image? Right now, in 2.1, they appear gray and black (see second image).